# Android HttpPost cause the app to crash

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send post request to my PHP page through java in android studio

and I tried the same code in eclipse but the same problem show, the app stop working.

I put the permission for the internet in the manifest.

My Code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String mail="aa@gmail.com",pass="pass";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8888/LoginTest/login.php");

        try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mail", mail));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        HttpResponse response=  httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        InputStream is= response.getEntity().getContent();

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        txt.setText(sb.toString());
        br.close();

        }
          catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My LogCat : https://www.dropbox.com/s/smhyoxdob66czr7/testLogCat.txt?dl=0

Comment: In order to help others understand your issue, please post a sample of the outputs of any logs (e.g. LogCat) or something to demonstrate a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, your application is crashing due to an exception, that is `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

This exception is thrown when you try to do lengthy time consuming tasks like network request and downloading the response on main thread, like you're doing in your `onCreate()`. Android doesn't like it. It keeps it frozen / un-responsive, which makes it angry and it kills your app.

The solution to use `AsyncTask`. The idea is to do lengthy tasks in background threads instead of main thread. Like as follow:

```
//this should be inside your Activity class
private class NetworkRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // your network code here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // set the result to your label
    }

}
```

and from your onCreate() call this task as follow:

```
new NetworkRequestTask(). execute();
```

It'll make android happy and responsive. It'll let your app running and won't kill it.